# How to get CheckBoxList to the right of its label? What is the width of a CheckBoxList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

How do I get the checkboxlist to appear to the right of the label?

The dropdownlist appears to the right of its label, with similar code, but the checkboxlist appears UNDER the label:

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTestVersions" runat="server" Text="Toetsversie:" AssociatedControlID="DropDownListTestVersions"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTestVersions" runat="server" Width="250" TabIndex="1" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTests0" runat="server" Text="Opties:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" TabIndex="2" Width="200">
        <asp:ListItem Width="200">Option 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Width="200">Option 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</p>
```

I tried to limit the width of the checkboxlist with several `Width="200"` but this did not help.

---

The answer (see below) is that the CheckBoxList is in fact a table and will always go to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to use HTML table, just keep label in one `td` and checkboxlist in an another `td`.

Comment: Thanks, I know there are many ways to solve a problem, but I try to understand the box model where every element has some width. Somehow it seems to me that the simplest way to solve my alignment problem might not need a table. Why does the dropdownlist align so easily?

Comment: when a dropdownlist get renders from server..it converts to a select tag..but where as a checkboxlist always renders as a table with input tags in it.hence we get the checkbox list in a new line...why dont you view the source of your file in browser..have a gr8 day amigo!!

Comment: Good point. I might as well put away with the CheckboxList and just make my own table with checkbox items. Then it is much more flexible with regard to caption etc.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
#lblTests0 { float: left; display:block; width: 100px; }
```

**Example:**

```
<p>
    <label id="lblTests0">Opties:</label>
    <table id="check1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="check1_0" type="checkbox" name="check1$0" value="Item 1"><label for="check1_0">Item 1</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="check1_1" type="checkbox" name="check1$1" value="Item 2"><label for="check1_1">Item 2</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</p>
```

Preview can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/NMWGh/

Comment: The TextAlign is default set to Right. Changing it to Left causes the CheckBox Items to change so that the text for each checkbox appears to the left of the checkbox. Apparently, the TextAlign works on the items, not on the checkboxlist as a whole. My problem is about the Label next to the checkboxlist, not about the texts of each individual checkbox in the list.

Comment: I see what your after does this address what you are trying to accomplish any better.